# Finding total and average salaries from 1000 lines of text

Tags: python, sum, average

I need to write a python program that reads 1000 lines of text and take the total and average of the salaries of each professor category (assistant, associate, full, all faculty). Here is the problem:

> A university posts its employee salary at
>   http://cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/Salary.txt. Each line in the file
>   consists of faculty first name, last name, rank, and salary (see
>   Exercise 13.16). Write a program to display the total salary for
>   assistant professors, associate professors, full professors, and all
>   faculty, respectively, and display the average salary for assistant
>   professors, associate professors, full professors, and all faculty,
>   respectively.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import urllib.request

def main():
    infile = urllib.request.urlopen('http://cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/Salary.txt')
    s = infile.read().decode().splitlines()

    asstTotal = 0
    asstCount = 0
    asscTotal = 0
    asscCount = 0
    fullTotal = 0
    fullCount = 0

    for line in s:
        if "assistant" in line:
            asstCount += 1
            asstTotal += int(float(s[3]))

        if "associate" in line:
            asscCount += 1
            asscTotal += int(float(s[3]))

        if "full" in line:
            fullCount += 1
            fullTotal += int(float(s[3]))

    allFacTotal = asstTotal + asscTotal + fullTotal
    avgAsst = int(asstTotal / asstCount)
    avgAssc = int(asscTotal / asscCount)
    avgFull = int(fullTotal / fullCount)
    avgAll = int(allFacTotal / 1000)

    print("Total assistant professor salary is", asstTotal)
    print("Total associate professor salary is", asscTotal)
    print("Total full professor salary is", fullTotal)
    print("Total faculty salary is", allFacTotal)
    print("Average assistant professor salary is", avgAsst)
    print("Average associate professor salary is", avgAssc)
    print("Average full professor salary is", avgFull)
    print("Average faculty salary is", avgAll)

main()
```

I'm not sure how to get the salaries from the respective professor ranks and totaling and averaging them. Any input would be much appreciated!

Result:

```
Total assistant professor salary is 24306418
Total associate professor salary is 27235856
Total full professor salary is 27631726
Total faculty salary is 79174000
Average assistant professor salary is 79174
Average associate professor salary is 79174
Average full professor salary is 79174
Average faculty salary is 79174
```

Comment: This code is **not even syntactically valid**, since you have left out the quotes on the URL and not put any body in the `for` loop. Please post a syntactically valid example and show what it does so far.

Comment: @Dan, thanks for pointing out the quotes on the URL. My `for` loop was empty because I wasn't sure what to start with, but I added something.

Comment: Use `strip()` `split()` on `line`. Then use `int()` to change string into integer. And use `print` to see what you get - to learn something.

Comment: @annabananana7, the formatting of the code example is still wrong and will not compile due to incorrect indentation of the `if` blocks. Have you actually tried it exactly as shown here? Please put together a complete example, run it, and **explain how the output you get differs from what you want**. (Otherwise we're just doing your homework for you...)

Comment: @Dan Editing error, it's the correct indentation in my program, just edited right before your comment

Comment: Getting there :). Now you're counting the number of professors of each rank, but you also need to extract their salaries and add those up, right? Python's [standard `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) is good for reading files of this type, or you can read about the [standard string functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) which @furas mentioned above.

Comment: One other problem is that you're reading the whole file contents into the string `s`. String objects don't have a `readline()` method so you should be getting an error there too if you're actually running it. You should be doing something more like `for line in s.splitlines():`

Comment: @Dan - Oh, yes, old good CSV - I forgot about it :)

Comment: @furas, I think your suggestion to use the standard string functions is actually much better for someone who is clearly just learning to use the language and to understand its data types.

Comment: @Dan, yes I was getting an error, but it's reading the file correctly now. I edited my code to show what I have so far - the print lines are just to make sure my code is right :)

Comment: You're pretty close to it. You just need to figure out how to `split` up the lines into words, convert the salaries to `float`ing point numbers, and total them up. Also, you might want to think about the bug you would encounter if, say, there was an Assistant Professor with "full" in their name.

Comment: @Dan I changed my code a bit, included the output in my edit. I don't get how there are so many places after the decimal when the file only has 1-2 places after the decimal for each line

Comment: @annabananana7, excellent observation. The short answer is that [IEEE floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) cannot represent decimal numbers with perfect precision. For a real-world financial application where you cannot afford to be making penny-roundoff errors left and right, you'd need to use something like the [`Decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)... for homework purposes I doubt it matters ;-)

Comment: Also, you have a couple of bugs here due to mixing up your variables and splitting the lines incorrectly (honestly I'm a bit surprised that it kinda-sorta runs) which are making all the salary sums wrong. Try `print(line)` right after `for` to see one part of what's wrong.

Comment: @Dan, wait really? It does run and I got numbers out of it (see `Result`), but what do you mean?

Comment: You got correct numbers for the number of faculty of each rank, but the rest are wrong due to 2 bugs. @kamikai's solution below shows the right values for the final answers.

Comment: @Dan Ok, I get the `splitlines()`, but now I'm getting an error: `could not convert string to float` and it stops at FirstName4...I'm not sure I'm following what the other bug(s) is/are

Comment: Try printing out the salaries as you add them up and you'll notice a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done to account for any type of rank, by building up a list of pay for each position in a dictionary, then simply dividing the sum by the length.

My example:

```
import urllib.request

def main():
    infile = urllib.request.urlopen('http://cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/Salary.txt')
    s = infile.read().decode().splitlines()

    pays = {}

    for line in s:
        *name, rank, pay = line.split()
        pays[rank] = pays.get(rank, []) + [float(pay)]

    for rank, sals in pays.items():
        avg = sum(sals) / len(sals)
        print("{:>10} ({:3}): ${:,.2f}".format(rank.title(), len(sals), avg))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the output:

```
Associate (344): $83,849.26
     Full (349): $102,229.37
Assistant (307): $65,949.55
```

Comment: Nice solution. Super Python-ic and especially big on the Py3k features :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request

def main():
    infile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/Salary.txt")

    asstSalTotal = 0
    asstTotal = 0
    asscSalTotal = 0
    asscTotal = 0
    fullSalTotal = 0
    fullTotal = 0

    for line in infile.readlines():
        data = line.decode().split()
        designation = data[2]
        if designation == "assistant":
            asstSalTotal += float(data[3])
            asstTotal += 1
        elif designation == "associate":
            asscSalTotal += float(data[3])
            asscTotal += 1
        elif designation == "full":
            fullSalTotal += float(data[3])
            fullTotal += 1

    allSalTotal = asstSalTotal + asscSalTotal + fullSalTotal
    allTotal = asstTotal + asscTotal + fullTotal

    print("Total Salary:\n\tAssistant:\t%d\n\tAssociate:\t%d\n\tFull:\t%d\n\tAll:\t%d\n\nAvg Salary:\n\tAssistant:\t%d\n\tAssociate:\t%d\n\tFull:\t%d\n\tAll:\t%d\n" % (asstSalTotal, asscSalTotal, fullSalTotal, allSalTotal, asstTotal, asscTotal, fullTotal, allTotal))


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In python2.7, use `urllib2.urlopen` and group salaries together by title with a table.

In python3, use `urllib.request.urlopen` and change `print ..` to `print(..)`

```
import urllib2

rs = urllib2.urlopen('http://cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/Salary.txt')
title_salaries = {}

for line in rs.read().split("\n"):
    _, _, title, salary = line.split(' ')
    if not title_salaries.has_key(title):
        title_salaries[title] = []

    title_salaries[title].append(float(salary))

for title, salaries in title_salaries.items():
    print title
    print 'avg:', sum(salaries) / len(salaries)
    print 'total:', sum(salaries)
    print
```

Comment: This is Python 2.7. @annabananana7 doesn't say so explicitly, but she's using Python 3 based on `print` as a function rather than statement. Hence `urllib.request`.

Comment: @Dan, thanks for catching that, answer has been updated